# Php send mail after threshold is reached, but only once. Running server-side cronjob per minute

Tags: php, email, cron

I'm currently working in PHP. I just figured out how to send an e-mail using PHP (needed to do some back-end stuff to get it running). The idea now is straightforward:

1) Every minute, a cronjob is scheduled to execute "x.php". This php script gets data from an external server.
2) I need the script to send an e-mail toward me if the value of the data gets below 15. 
3) However, I don't want to be spammed every minute if this value stays below 15 for a while, so it should only send me a notification once, and then for each time the value gets above 15 and THEN below 15 again.

My code is as following. I realize that this will not work since $sentMail = 1; will be executed every time I run the script. But how could I do it?$sentMail = 1;

```
if ($nettoValue < 15) {


            if ($sentMail == 1) {
                $subject = 'Dit is de titel van het test bericht';
                $email = 'Dit is de inhoud van het test bericht';
                $to = 'pbla@bla.com';
                $from = 'bla@bla.com';

                $headers   = array();
                $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
                $headers[] = "From: bla <{$from}>";
                $headers[] = "Reply-To: bla <{$from}>";
                //$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
                $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

                mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers), "-    f".$from );
                $sentMail = 0;
            }
            else {}
        }

        if ($nettoValue > 15) {
            $sentMail = 1;
        }
```

Thanks in advance for the help :)

EDIT: So apparently I'm still doing something wrong, as I get a server error as soon as this script is in the page:

```
if ($nettoValue < 15) {
                $fname = "/httpdocs/sentmail.txt";
                $fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
                $sentMail = fread($fhandle,"1");
                fclose($fhandle);

                if (strcmp($sentMail,'1')==0) {
                    $subject = 'Test';
                    $email = 'Test';
                    $to = 'bla@gmail.com';
                    $from = 'bla@gmail.com';

                    $headers   = array();
                    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
                    $headers[] = "From: BECC <{$from}>";
                    $headers[] = "Reply-To: BECC <{$from}>";
                    //$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
                    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

                    mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers), "-f".$from );

                    $fname = "/httpdocs/sentmail.txt";
                    $fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");

                    fwrite($fhandle,"0");
                    fclose($fhandle);
                }
                else {}
            }

            if ($nettoValue > 15) {
                $fname = "/httpdocs/sentmail.txt";
                $fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");

                fwrite($fhandle,"1");
                fclose($fhandle);
            }
```

Some things I noted: The file is not being written to, so probably not read from as well. If I remove the if statement for sentMail == 1 I do get an e-mail immediately. What should I do?

Comment: Put the current number in a file with fopen(),fputs(),fclose(). Then, compare this value with the current one when the script will be launched again.

Comment: you need somehow store previous value and alert only if `previous < 15 && new > 15`, files/database are your options

Comment: I'll look into the fopen(), fputs(), and fclose() functions. Thanks for the tips guys!~

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. The code is fine, however crontabs are not allowed to edit other files automatically. If I run the script manually, it does send an e-mail.